# JBoss EAP 6.1 not able to shutdown with command

Tags: jboss

I am not able to shutdown jboss server with the below command.

### Command :

```
    JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect controller=$SERVER_IP_ADDRESS:$SERVER_PORT command=:shutdown
```

---

Each time I was killing the server to restart which is not a good process to do. as we are moving to PROD environment we should use shutdown command to stop the server instead of killing
  I am getting the below error. Please help.

### Server Log :

```
    jboss@devkopmdmh01.corp.ybusa.net::/usr/local/prod/jboss/jboss-eap-6.1/jboss-as/bin > ./shutdownMDM.sh


  org.jboss.as.cli.CliInitializationException: Failed to connect to the controller
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.initCommandContext(CliLauncher.java:280)

Caused by: org.jboss.as.cli.CommandLineException: The controller is not available at 10.0.15.162:8080
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.tryConnection(CommandContextImpl.java:951)

        ... 8 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://10.0.15.162:8080. The connection timed out
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:129)

        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://10.0.15.162:8080. The connection timed out
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:131)

        ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The JBoss CLI is attempting to connect to the native management endpoint for the running JBoss and send a shutdown command.  It looks like it's trying to send to 10.0.15.162:8080 which is not the right port (most likely).

Take a look in your bin/jboss-cli.xml file which should contain the host and port to connect to.  For example:

```
<default-controller>
    <host>localhost</host>
    <port>9999</port>
</default-controller>
```

Comment: Solved.                                                                             JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown